How to show that orthogonal states can always be distinguished
Hello I am learning quantum information and encountered a problem as follows:
Show that orthogonal states can always be distinguished. That is, consider a set of
orthogonal states ${|\psi_i⟩}$ with $i=1,2,3...n$. in a Hilbert space, H with $\dim H \ge n$ and construct a measurement, ${A_i}$ such that if outcome $i$ is obtained, the system must have been in the state $|\psi_i⟩$.
I am thinking about constructing a set of measurements $A_i$ such that $A_i=|\psi_i\rangle\langle \psi_i|$, then if we measure $\langle \psi_i|A_i|\psi_i\rangle=1,\langle \psi_i|A_j|\psi_i\rangle=0$. But it seems I should also consider the case where $\dim H > n$, but I have no idea how this might affect my conclusion?

Can't you just complete ${ | \psi_i \rangle }$ to the orthogonal basis and measure in this basis?

cross-posted on https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/837131/58382

You can also note that the set of projectors ${\vert\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i\vert}$ for $i\in [n]$ together with $I - \sum_i\vert\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i\vert$ form a valid POVM and lets you distinguish the $n$ states you are interested in and the case where your state is not one of those $n$ states.
